# Extract Text From EditText and Print in TextView

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview

I have a question:

I have entered a text in EditText, '***My Name is Khan***'

I just want to print just 'Khan' in TextView (not '***My Name is Khan***', just '***Khan***' I want in TextView).

How to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Parse your string using split.

```
String[] s = edittext.getText.toString().split(Pattern.quote(" "));
```

Then get the last word.

```
String name = s[s.length-1];
```

Now set it

```
textView.setText(name);
```

Comment: bro what do 'length - 1' do here? Actually I am still learning it.

Comment: Arrays always counts from 0'th position to n'th position. Consider, if you are having an array of two names. String[] names = {"alice", "bob"}; If you asks for its length it will give you "2" as length. But if you want to fetch the first name, you will query like name[0]. This will give you the first name. So the last item of the array is in the position of length-1. In this case 2-1 is the last name position.